# How to get JSON data for US country

Tags: angularjs, json

I have to highlight US(Overall state and city as well)by using google map. Right now i'm hard coding lat long values.I need to bring those coordinates from json data and needs to highlight US City. And I don't know from where i need to get those json coordinates data to highlight and how to implement or assign json data in code.(need JSON data)

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Controller</title>
        <script src = "scripts/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

        <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
        <script src="scripts/vendor/ng-map.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link href="styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            #map {
                height:420px;
                width:100%;
            }
            .infoWindowContent {
                font-size:  14px !important;
                border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }
            h2 {
                margin-bottom:0;
                margin-top: 0;
            }

            .informationcontent
            {
                overflow:hidden;
                font-size:12px;
            }
            .glyiconsize
            {
                font-size:20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--<h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2> -->

        <div ng-app = "mapsApp" ng-controller = "MapCtrl">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <!-- <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
         <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
    </div>-->        
        </div>

        <script>

            //Data
            var cities = [
                {
                    city: 'Toronto',
                    desc: 'This is the best city in the world!',
                    lat: 43.7000,
                    long: -79.4000
                },
                {
                    city: 'New York',
                    desc: 'This city is aiiiiite!',
                    lat: 40.6700,
                    long: -73.9400
                },
                {
                    city: 'Chicago',
                    desc: 'This is the second best city in the world!',
                    lat: 41.8819,
                    long: -87.6278
                },
                {
                    city: 'Los Angeles',
                    desc: 'This city is live!',
                    lat: 34.0500,
                    long: -118.2500
                },
                {
                    city: 'Las Vegas',
                    desc: 'Sin City...\'nuff said!',
                    lat: 36.0800,
                    long: -115.1522
                }
            ];

            /*  var cities = [
             {
             city : 'Chicago',
             desc : 'This is the second best city in the world!',
             lat : 41.8819,
             long : -87.6278
             }

             ];*/


            var mainApp = angular.module("mapsApp", []);

            mainApp.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                }

                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

                $scope.markers = [];

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                var createMarker = function (info) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: $scope.map,
                        icon: 'images/user.png',
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
                        title: info.city
                    });
                    //  marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';
                    marker.content = '<div class="informationcontent"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-2"><img src="images/infouserprofile.png" width="30" height="30"></div><div class="col-md-7">Mathew Christy<br>NV,USA</div><div class="col-md-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right glyiconsize"></span></div>' + '</div></div>';
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        // infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
                        infoWindow.setContent('</h2>' + marker.content);
                        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                        for (var j = 0; j < marker.length; j++) {
                            marker[j].setIcon("user.png");
                        }
                    });

                    $scope.markers.push(marker);

                }

                for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(cities[i]);
                }
// Here i hardcoded for highlight US City--need JSon data to highlight US City Properly
                var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                    {lat: 48.494702, lng: -124.787546},
                    {lat: 49.070385, lng: -95.177143},
                    {lat: 49.377565, lng: -95.151013},
                    {lat: 44.832106, lng: -66.926113},
                    {lat: 25.915679, lng: -97.248488},
                    {lat: 29.044624, lng: -103.336787},
                    {lat: 31.392591, lng: -108.196974},
                    {lat: 32.567267, lng: -114.807874},
                    {lat: 32.545243, lng: -117.185707}
                ];


                var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: flightPlanCoordinates, //How to give JSON Data Here
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });

                flightPath.setMap($scope.map);

                $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: You can use Highchart library to prepare geo chart. here is the link you can go through http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo. Also it is working on JSON so this might be the solution you are looking for.